# C++ , Member function passed as template argument

Tags: c++, function, templates, arguments, parameter-passing

I would like to pass the function eval2(T c, T &d), which is the member function in the class Algo1

```
Algo1.h
#ifndef ALGO1_H
#define ALGO1_H

#include "Algo2.h"

template <typename T>
class Algo1
{
    private: T a, b;

    public:
    Algo1() : a(0), b(0) {}
    Algo1(T a_, T b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {}

    void anal(T &c);
    void eval1(T c);
    void eval2(T c, T &d);
    friend void get(Algo1 &al, T &a, T &b);
};
#endif
```

as the template argument in anal(T &c) function.

```
Algo1.hpp
#ifndef ALGO1_HPP
#define ALGO1_HPP

template <typename T>
void Algo1<T>::anal(T &c) {
    Algo2<T>::process(eval2<T>, b, c);} //Pass the  member function, wrong

template <typename T>
void Algo1<T>::eval1(T c) {     a += c; }

template <typename T>
void Algo1<T>::eval2(T c, T &d) { d = a + b + c;}

#endif
```

In practice, eval2() represents some cost function working with member data. The "destination" class containing method process() looks like

```
Algo2.h
#ifndef ALGO2_H
#define ALGO2_H

template <typename T>
class Algo2
{
    public:

    template <typename Function>
    static void process(Function f, T &x, T &res);
};
#endif

Algo2.hpp
#ifndef ALGO2_HPP
#define ALGO2_HPP

template <typename T>
template <typename Function>
void Algo2<T>::process(Function f, T &x, T &res)  { f(x, res); } //Call passed function as static

#endif
```

Unfortunately, eval2(T c, T &d) is the member function processing member data, it can not be declared as static. However, outside the class it can not be called without the object. Hence, the function process() is unable to call the passed function as the static function. To fix the problem and extract the data, the friend function get(Algo1  &al, T &a, T &b ) was declared and defined

```
template <typename T>
inline void get(Algo1 <T> &al, T &a, T &b )
{
    a = al.a;
    b = a1.b;
}
```

It was "built" into the non-member function eval3()

```
template <typename T>
inline void eval3(T c, T &d)
{
    Algo1 <T> alg;
    T a, b;
    get(alg, a, b);
}
```

and the function anal() was refined to call eval3 instead of eval 2 to the form of

```
 template <typename T>
 void Algo1<T>::anal(T &c)
 {
    Algo2<T>::process(eval3<T>, b, c); //Pass the function OK
 }
```

I am having two questions:

1. Is there any more comfortable way how to pass a member function while keeping the call it as static?
2. where to declare and define get() and eval3() functions to avoid the error

   Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl    get(class Algo1 &,double &,double &)" (?get@@YAXAAV?$Algo1@N@@AAN1@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl eval3(double,double &)"

Thank you very much for your help.

**_____________Comment________________**

The second point has been solved. Instead of the declaration

```
 friend void get(Algo1 &al, T &a, T &b);
```

it needs to be declared like this

```
 template <typename T>
 friend void get(Algo1 &al, T &a, T &b);
```

Comment: You might want to tweak the name of the function a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is there any more comfortable way how to pass a member function while keeping the call it as static?

With C++11 and lambda, you may do

```
template <typename T>
void Algo1<T>::anal(T &c) {
    Algo2<T>::process([=](T a1, T& a2) { return this->eval2(a1, a2); }, this->b, c);
}
```

Before, you have to create your functor manually, something like:

```
template<typename T>
class MyFunctor
{
public:
    explicit(Algo1<T>* algo1) : algo1(algo1) {}

    void operator () (T a1, T& a2) const
    {
        algo1->eval2(a1, a2);
    }
private:
    Algo1<T>* algo1;
};
```

And then:

```
template <typename T>
void Algo1<T>::anal(T &c) {
    Algo2<T>::process(MyFunctor<T>(this), this->b, c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I am not familiar with new C++ norm. How does the functor look like, is there any difference from the "old" norm?

Comment: @Tomas: added the C++03 solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get` function prototype in the class as a friend function (w/o templates) and the definition prototype as a template function do not match. Hence the unresolved external as the linker is probably searching for a definition of the friend get function.